# How to redirect .com to .net domain, but keep .com in url?

Tags: url, redirect, dns

i have two websites, one is .com the other one is .net on different hosting accounts and platforms, and domains registered on different registrars. I need to set up the environment from next year, the .com domain to point to the .net website, but the url to remain site.com

.net is joomla website (php/mysql on apache) with .htaccess file i can easily configure (if i need to) but i've read somewhere that i can just park the domain on this account and redirect the domain to this servers dns. Is this true? Anyway please let me know how can i achieve this.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check your .com hosting administration interface, some providers have a option that allow you to "masked" redirection of your URL. Unfortunately, masked redirection can be recognized by browsers such as untrustworthy.

Better solution is moving your .com domain to same hosting accout / provider that .net. Then you can set .com domain as a .net domain alias and you can use only 1 hosting service.